# Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://127.0.0.1  ==> Ruby (Rack) application could not be started, Can someone help?

A source file that the application requires, is missing.

```
*
  It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
*
  A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
```

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

```
Error message:
    no such file to load -- bundler
Exception class:
    LoadError
Application root:
    /var/www/project
Backtrace:
    #   File    Line    Location
    0   /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb     36  in `require'
    1   /home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb     36  in `require'
    2   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb   325     in `prepare_app_process'
    3   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    155     in `block in initialize_server'
    4   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb   572     in `report_app_init_status'
    5   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    153     in `initialize_server'
    6   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     204     in `start_synchronously'
    7   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     180     in `start'
    8   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb    128     in `start'
    9   /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   253     in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
    10  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  132     in `lookup_or_add'
    11  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   246     in `block in spawn_rack_application'
    12  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  82  in `block in synchronize'
    13      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
    14  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  79  in `synchronize'
    15  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   244     in `spawn_rack_application'
    16  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   137     in `spawn_application'
    17  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   275     in `handle_spawn_application'
    18  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     357     in `server_main_loop'
    19  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb     206     in `start_synchronously'
    20  /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server    99  in `'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I'm running into the same problem now.

Answer (score 2):

`gem install bundler` should do the trick here. "Error message: no such file to load -- bundler" is the relevant line. You'll probably need to run `bundle install` after installing the bundler gem as well.

Comment: I have the same problem as the op. I tried "gem install bundler" and then "bundle install" instinctively after seeing the error message, but the error message still appears, even after restarting nginx.